# Error when exporting bacpac using DacServices

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database

I am trying to export a bacpac with code, but I get a error that says

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServicesException: 'Database source is not a supported version of SQL Server tcp:xxxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433: test.'

I can export it with SSMS (export data-tier application) without any problems.

My testprogram is C# .NET 4, have imported Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac-x86 nuget.

Samplecode:

```
var azureServices = new DacServices($"Data Source={source},1433;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=False;User ID={user};Password={password}");
azureServices.Message += AzureServices_Message;
azureServices.ProgressChanged += AzureServices_ProgressChanged;
azureServices.ExportBacpac(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "test" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), "test");
```

What am I doing wrong? Or have Microsoft breaked something in Azure sql?

Edit: I need to download the bacpac locally, thats why I dont use the rest api to export to blob storage.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using a REST API instead:

Sample Request:

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/resourceGroups/sqlcrudtest-4799/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sqlcrudtest-5961/databases/testdb/export?api-version=2014-04-01
```

Request body:

```
{
  "storageKeyType": "StorageAccessKey",
  "storageKey": "sdlfkjdsf+sdlfkjsdlkfsjdfLDKFJSDLKFDFKLjsdfksjdflsdkfD2342309432849328479324/3RSD==",
  "storageUri": "https://test.blob.core.windows.net/bacpacs/testbacpac.bacpac",
  "administratorLogin": "dummyLogin",
  "administratorLoginPassword": "Un53cuRE!",
  "authenticationType": "SQL"
}
```

For more information, please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/Databases%20-%20Import%20Export/Export) documentation.

Comment: I need to doanload the bacpac locally, so this would need a "download step" also.